# SwiftUI - UserDefaults array of strings error

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a problem when trying to save array of strings into the UserDefaults. I have a simple ObservableObject with one property:

```
class AppManagerModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var userData = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "userData") as? [String] ?? [String]()
}
```

Then when i try to update that data from the view

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(appManagerModel.userData.append("Test"), forKey: "userData")
```

I get the following error- "Attempt to insert non-property list object () for key userData"

Comment: append returns void. Append then set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.append` returns `Void` . You need to append to the array then set.

```
class AppManagerModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var userData = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "userData") as? [String] ?? [String]()
    
    func addUserData(_ data: String) {
        userData.append(data)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(userData, forKey: "userData")
    }
}
```

Keep your persistence logic hidden in `AppManagerModel` rather than putting it in your `View`.